# Usability of Python library PyGithub in production grade projects

Tags: github, pygithub

Just wanted to know if it is a good idea to go head with the **PyGithub**.

**I am not asking for opinions**. What I have learned is that before using any library, one of the most important things that we should look for is the backing(of community/organization) that the library has.

Just got curious and suspicious by looking at the note at the bottom of it's GitHub page(https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub), which says :

**Maintainership**

> We're actively seeking maintainers that will triage
>   issues and pull requests and cut releases. If you work on a project
>   that leverages PyGitHub and have a vested interest in keeping the code
>   alive and well, send an email to someone in the MAINTAINERS file.

The request seems so humble. Looks like this library is not having sufficient maintainers.

I understand that people might be using this library in personal projects, but do any organizations(that you are aware of) use this in production grade projects.

I have tried my best not to sound like asking for opinions. Please let me know if this OP can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let PyGithub speak for it self:

- Initial commit was back in [early 2012](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/tree/3e33f3892741e26741383920145e9def6becaae6)
- It has over 1800 commits with latest commit being 4 days ago
- It has over [800 closed issues](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed) and [600 merged pull requests](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/pulls?q=is%3Apr%20is%3Aclosed)
- It has over 200 direct contributors with 6 maintainers
- If you look at dependency graph, it is included as a dependency in [6200 repositories](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/network/dependents)
- Unfortunately, on Stack Overflow, there is only 95 questions tagged with PyGithub tag. Maybe it would be harder for you to find answers to the problem you are facing. But on the bright side, you can always search for issues on their github repository. You will find something there definitely .

---

Best approach for you would be to check if PyGithub suits your needs. Check if their API has you covered for everything you need. If you really find something is missing, you can always mail maintainers or open issue at their Github repo.

Comment: @Dino Paher I appreciate your well researched response. What I am specifically looking for is whether this library is being used in production grade projects(to keep it simple, whether used by any organization). I appreciate the fact that over 6200 repos are using this library,but by just browsing through first few pages, it looks like they are personal repos of individuals. But since this library has been out there since 2012, I believe it would be active in future too. But still hoping someone to share his/her experience of using it in a production environment.

Comment: If there is a way for sorting dependency graph by stars, you could sort by stars. On this link https://libraries.io/pypi/PyGithub , you can see `UsedBy` section or https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#projects-using-pygithub .

Comment: Please note also, not all "big production" firms are used to talk about what are they using internally for production. This would put them at risk when bug is discovered at library.

Comment: Thanks for https://libraries.io/pypi/PyGithub.The fact that Spinnker and Apache Spark use PyGitHub is quite assuring.

Comment: You pick whatever suits your needs and time frame. If things go sideways, you adapt. Glad I helped you in some way